# Notice: Undefined index: file in upload.php

Tags: php, html

upload.php:

```php
<?php


include_once 'dbh.php';

$target_dir = "project/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

$uploadOk = 1;

$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {


    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

    if($check !== false) {

        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";

        $uploadOk = 1;

    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";

        $uploadOk = 0;

    }
}
?>
```

HTML:

```html
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label class="custom-file-input" for="file" >
  </label>

  <input id="file" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file" accept="image/*" style="visibility: hidden">
</form>
```

Error:

> Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\upload.php on line 6

Comment: Because your accessing the `file` before it available in `$_FILES`

Comment: **1st :** Because your accessing the `file` before it available in `$_FILES`.

**2nd :** Move your code into inside the `isset()`.

**3rd :** you need to add submit input . `<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">`

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES` is superglobal, that is right, but if the form is not sent, the file-input from the HTML form is not set.

In this case, `$_FILES` is empty and `$_FILES['file']` is an undefined index.